# Docker Multistage build replace None None name and tag automatically

Tags: docker

I have a multistage build in which I am have a few named stages

```
From foo as stage1
.
.
.
From stage1 as bar
.
.
.
From bar as final
```

When I build this docker file and run docker image ls I get something like this

```
REPOSITORY                                                          TAG 
my_repo                                                              latest
<none>                                                              <none>
<none>                                                              <none>
```

I know that I can use the --target to build the intermediate stages but when I have a big complex build it can get kinda annoying. Ive already named the stages in the docker file. Is there a way to automatically propagate the to images based on my names in the docker file? Ive looked but cant find anything besides using --target multiple times...

Ideally some build command that when ran would lead to a docker image ls that looks like this

```
REPOSITORY                                                          TAG 
final                                                              latest
bar                                                                latest
stage1                                                             latest
```

Comment: Do you have a use case for needing to keep the intermediate build stages beyond the final image build?  I'm used to seeing multi-stage builds where earlier stages include a full tool chain and compilation environment, and the final image only contains the built application; once the application is built you don't need the build environment any more.

Comment: Yes I have a similar setup but I am trying to debug the none none tags are a pain because I am on a shared machine and they start to take a lot of space. Pruning is also a big pain because some of the intermediate stages take a long time to build. If I build each stage with --target then I can remove what I want but its kinda repetitive.

Comment: [This article](https://forums.docker.com/t/tag-intermediate-build-stages-multi-stage-build/34795) suggests using labels, but when I try what they have it tells me "Label is an invalid filter"